# How can i get only one user by id?

Tags: java, rest, annotations, postman, httpresponse

```
class UserRepository {
 public User getById(long id) {
        logger.info("Get User by id: " + id);
        return entityManager.find(User.class, id);
    }
}
class UserRest {
@GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUserById(@PathParam("id") long id) throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/messenger/api/user/");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode != 200) {
            System.out.println("Error: Response code " + responseCode);
        }
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                response.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            scanner.close();
            String responseData = response.toString();
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(
                    "C:\\Users\\ETHAN\\Downloads\\My_Java_Solutions-main (7)\\My_Java_Solutions-main\\service_example\\output.txt"); 
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
            printWriter.print(responseData);
            printWriter.close();
            logger.info("Data saved to file.");
            return userRepository.getById(id);
    }
}
```

**The result i get in txt file**
[{"id":15,"nick_name":"freddy","userType":"user"},{"id":17,"nick_name":"samy","userType":"user"},{"id":29,"nick_name":"klien","userType":"user"},{"id":20,"nick_name":"sam","userType":"user"}]
**The result i wanted to be in txt file is**
{"id":15,"nick_name":"freddy","userType":"user"}

Comment: You get the entire user collection. You append them all to 'response' and then write them all to the file.  That's why they're all in the file!  I don't know this 'messenger' API, why can't you just get the one user?   But assuming you can't, then you need to iterate through the responses (as you already do) and find the id you want.  Then only write *that single entry* to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your code for the “http://localhost:8080/messenger/api/user/” endpoint? Seems like you never pass the ID to the endpoint, so the query is returning more users than you want.

Edit the URL to include the userID, like so:

Switch

```
URL url = new URL("localhost:8080/messenger/api/user/");
```

with

```
URL url = new URL("localhost:8080/messenger/api/user/"+ id);
```

or filter the responses based on userID when it returns the response by checking the userIDs on each line in your while loop for the scanner, before appending that line to the final result.

Comment: I deploy this project to jboss server and then i type this url in postman using the http request GET http://localhost:8080/messenger/api/user/15 and then i get the response in post man {"id":15,"nick_name":"freddy","userType":"user"} but in the txt file i get all the users. @lilhitchcock

Comment: The code you show uses the url `http://localhost:8080/messenger/api/user/`, which does not contain any user id. Therefore the REST call returns the whole list.

Comment: @HIZAM Okay, if you've tested that endpoint elsewhere. Then i'd say you just need to append the userID onto the end of your URL. Look's like you forgot to add the ID on the end, therefore you're requesting all of them, instead of just one specific user. 

Try replacing 

URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/messenger/api/user/");
with 
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/messenger/api/user/"+ id);
or
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/messenger/api/user/"+ id.toString());

Comment: I tried the last two URLS i get Content removed from location C:\Users\Ethan\EAP-7.3.0\standalone\data\content\26\c517d8d8812bdd8ceab6ea4c094b48a7f99444\content

Comment: @HIZAM, it's tough to say without having you provide more information. Since you're only dealing with a few users, I would suggest that you add an if statement inside your scanner's while loop. So only the line matching your usersID parameter will be appended to the text file.

Or, reasearch the requirements regarding your endpoint  and try to learn how you need to structure your URL with userID to request one at a time.